# How can i make that the backgroundworker will report the progress items only once?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
foreach (string file in filePathList)
{
    try
    {
        _busy.WaitOne();
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
        {
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            if (File.ReadAllText(file).IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                resultsoftextfound.Add(file + "  " + textToSearch[i]);
                numberoffiles++;
                prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = file, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString(), Report3 = textToSearch[i] });
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
            }
        }
            numberofdirs++;
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                label1.Visible = true;
            });
        }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         restrictedFiles.Add(file);
         continue;
     }
}
```

The class MyProgress

```
public class MyProgress
{
    public string Report1 { get; set; }
    public string Report2 { get; set; }
    public string Report3 { get; set; }
}
```

In the inner loop when textToSearch contain more then one item for example:

> hi hello world

If more then two words exist in the same file it will report the same file twice or three times according to how many words/text found in the file.

How can i keep the loop to find the text in the file more then once but reportprogress the file only once?

This line to report only once.
If in a file it found 2 or 3 results report only once. In many cases it's reporting twice or three times the same file.

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
```

Later on progresschanged i'm adding the files as strings to a listView

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<MyProgress> mypro = e.UserState as List<MyProgress>;
    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro[0].Report1);
    label15.Text = mypro[0].Report2;
    label15.Visible = true;
    if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count > 9)
        textBox4.Enabled = true;
}
```

This line add the files results to the listView

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro[0].Report1);
```

I don't want to change the loop only to make it to report each file after it finish to search to be reported once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what your code does now, and a precise description of what you want it to do instead, it's difficult if not impossible to know for sure what it is you want.

But if I understand the question correctly, the solution is as simple as maintaining a flag that indicates whether you've reported the current file or not, and only report the file if the flag hasn't been set yet. E.g.:

```
foreach (string file in filePathList)
{
    try
    {
        _busy.WaitOne();
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        bool reportedFile = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
        {
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            if (File.ReadAllText(file).IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                resultsoftextfound.Add(file + "  " + textToSearch[i]);

                if (!reportedFile)
                {
                    numberoffiles++;
                    prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = file, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString(), Report3 = textToSearch[i] });
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
                    reportedFile = true;
                }
            }
        }

        numberofdirs++;
        label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
            label1.Visible = true;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        restrictedFiles.Add(file);
        continue;
    }
}
```

I will also point out that you seem to be using a `List<MyProgress>` to pass information for the `ReportProgress()` method for no good reason. The list only ever has one element in it, so you might as well just pass the `MyProgress` value itself, rather than a list containing that value.

If the above does not address your question, please improve the question so that it is more understandable.

Comment: Peter with the MyProgress List do you mean i should something like: MyProgress myp = new MyProgress(); and then for example myp.Report1 = file; and the to teportprogress myp ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Then in your handler, you can just cast back to `MyProgress`, i.e. `MyProgress mypro = (MyProgress)e.UserState;`.